# C# Adding items to list causes duplicates

Tags: c#, mysql, list, loops, iteration

I want to make a loop which adds an object to a list. Whenever I do this it seems to keep adding the same object.

```
private List<Events> GetEvents()
        {
            List<Events> dataEvents = new List<Events>();
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Events";
            var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                Events x = new Events(rdr.GetInt32(0), rdr.GetString(1), rdr.GetInt32(2), rdr.GetInt32(3), rdr.GetDateTime(4));
                dataEvents.Add(x);
            }

            con.Close();
            return dataEvents;
        }

List<Events> newEvent = GetEvents();
```

Here's how I constructed my Events class:

```
public class Events
    {
        private static int _ID;
        private static string _Type;
        private static int _UserID;
        private static int _LokaalID;
        private static DateTime _Created_On;
        public Events(int id, string type, int UserID, int LokaalID, DateTime Created_On)
        {
            _ID = id;
            _Type = type;
            _UserID = UserID;
            _LokaalID = LokaalID;
            _Created_On = Created_On;
        }


    public int ID { get { return _ID; } }
    public string Type { get { return _Type; } }
    public int UserID { get { return _UserID; } }
    public int LokaalID { get { return _LokaalID; } }
    public DateTime Created_On { get { return _Created_On; } }

    }
```

[Screenshot for objects in list or check below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byb5G.png)

- ```
    [0]
    ID  38  int
    LokaalID    1   int
    Type    "check_in"  string
    UserID  114 int
  ```

- ```
    [1]
    ID  38  int
    LokaalID    1   int
    Type    "check_in"  string
    UserID  114 int
  ```
- ```
    [2]
    ID  38  int
    LokaalID    1   int
    Type    "check_in"  string
    UserID  114 int
  ```

This is what my database looks like so you can see it's not duplicated in my database:

[Screenshot of database content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTOwE.png)

Comment: It seems like you have those duplicates in your database

Comment: @Steeeve I checked my database and that's not the issue.

Comment: ´SELECT * FROM Events` is a bad idea (but it can't create duplicates). What columns do you have in your database? I can't see from the shown code any issues that could produce duplicates. Are you connecting to the right database?

Comment: These are the colums:
Events
Users
Rooms
I'm connected to the right database and just double checked.

Comment: Then please add your `Events` class code.

Comment: @Steeeve added it to the post

Comment: Thanks for letting me discover the problem in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event class have private fields that are static, hence the values for these fields are common to all of your events instances…

Here would be the correct code. It could be simplified, depending on the .NET version you are using.

```cs
public class Events
{
    private int _ID;
    private string _Type;
    private int _UserID;
    private int _LokaalID;
    private DateTime _Created_On;
    public Events(int id, string type, int UserID, int LokaalID, DateTime Created_On)
    {
        _ID = id;
        _Type = type;
        _UserID = UserID;
        _LokaalID = LokaalID;
        _Created_On = Created_On;
    }


    public int ID { get { return _ID; } }
    public string Type { get { return _Type; } }
    public int UserID { get { return _UserID; } }
    public int LokaalID { get { return _LokaalID; } }
    public DateTime Created_On { get { return _Created_On; } }
}
```

The modern way (C# 9) to write this would be

```cs
public class Events
{
    public int ID { get; init; }
    public string Type { get; init; }
    public int UserID { get; init; }
    public int LokaalID { get; init; }
    public DateTime Created_On { get; init; }
}
```

Side note: Why call your class Events, when it models one event?

Comment: What do you mean with models one event?

Comment: For one row in your database, you create one instance of your class Events. Doesn't one row represent a single event?

Comment: If that is the case, it would be better to name your class Event, without a plural. Then if you use a collection of objects of type Event, that collection could be called Events. For instance: var Events = new List<Event>(); It would make things clearer when you or someone else reads the code.

Answer (score 0):

Laurent's nailed it; never use `static` unless you know exactly what it's for.. Make your events look like this:

```
public class Events
{

    public Events(int id, string type, int UserID, int LokaalID, DateTime Created_On)
    {
        ID = id;
        Type = type;
        UserID = UserID;
        LokaalID = LokaalID;
        Created_On = Created_On;
    }


    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int LokaalID  { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created_On  { get; set; }

}
```

But once you've fixed that, try this; you'll probably thank me later for different reasons!

- Open the NuGet Package Manager for the project,
- Search for *Dapper*
  [image]
- Install it and put the following code in your app instead:

```
        private List<Events> GetEvents()
        {
            using var con = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            return conn.Query<Event>("SELECT * FROM Events").ToList();
        }
```

Yep.. That's all you have to do*; Dapper will make the objects, open/close the connection, read the data, populate it into the objects etc..

*Well, unless your C# property names don't align with the column names, in which case, use `AS` to rename your columns so they *do* match:

```
//assume the column is called EventId and the C# prop is ID
conn.Query<Event>("SELECT EventId as ID, ... FROM Events").ToList()
```

To do parameterized queries:

```
conn.Query<Event>("SELECT * FROM Events WHERE ID = @someId", new { someId = 123 }).ToList()
```

It does boatloads more, but this should get you started and mean you don't have to spend hours writing the most tedious `GetInt, GetString, Get.. Get..` code known to humankind..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the static modifier from your fields:

```
public class Events
{
    private int _ID;
    private string _Type;
    private int _UserID;
    private int _LokaalID;
    private DateTime _Created_On;

    public Events(int id, string type, int UserID, int LokaalID, DateTime Created_On)
    {
        _ID = id;
        _Type = type;
        _UserID = UserID;
        _LokaalID = LokaalID;
        _Created_On = Created_On;
    }


    public int ID { get { return _ID; } }
    public string Type { get { return _Type; } }
    public int UserID { get { return _UserID; } }
    public int LokaalID { get { return _LokaalID; } }
    public DateTime Created_On { get { return _Created_On; } }
}
```